Monthly payments after adjustment in SSMS
In SSMS
Table mempay
Id.  Code    AMT.         STDT.             EDDT
148.         1000.      01-01-23.    01-31-23
148.   26.   -1200.     01-01-23.    06-30-23
148.             1000.      02-01-23.    02-28-23
148.            1000.      03-01-23.    03-31-23
148.           1000.      04-01-23.    04-30-23
148.            1000.      05-01-23.    05-31-23
148.           1000.      06-01-23.    06-30-23
148.            800.      07-01-23.     07-30-23
148.           800.      08-01-23.    08-31-23
148.         800.       09-01-23.    09-30-23
148.          -1600.      09-01-23.    10-31-23
148.           800.      10-01-23.    10-31-23
Requirement
1st check code 26 then divide amt with number of month from stdt to eddt
2nd check code 26 stdt and eddt then check other records in table within that stdt and eddt then if any records within that date range update amt for rest of the records base on code 26 amt (if code 26 amt negative then subtract other records within stdt and eddt in table, if positive then add)
3rd after adding or subtracting amt for rest of the record display only each month records not code 26 record with stdt 01-01-23 through eddt 06-30-23.
If code 03 then verify month and remove from final output
Final output:
Id.  Code    AMT.         STDT.             EDDT
148.         800.      01-01-23.    01-31-23
148.          800.      02-01-23.    02-28-23
148.            800.      03-01-23.    03-31-23
148.           800.      04-01-23.    04-30-23
148.            800.      05-01-23.    05-31-23
148.           800.      06-01-23.    06-30-23
148.            800.      07-01-23.     07-30-23
148.           800.      08-01-23.    08-31-23
